# Full of "\0" in xml file

Tags: c#

I have a xml serialize method as below and always works fine except the moment when Operation System suspend or shutdown. Sometimes, the serialized file content was changed to "\0" but size is correct.
[File screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADMql.png)
I looked up the source code from [SteamWriter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,a6be789c44dd7cbc), and suspect that the memory was cleared at that time so the pointer's value should be "\0". But it just my guess. Please let me know if you have any idea about this issue.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
settings.Indent = true;
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, t);
    }
    string xmlString = textWriter.ToString();

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlString))
    {
        LogUtil.LogError(string.Format("{0} content is empty.", xmlPath));
    }
    else if(xmlString.StartsWith("\0"))
    {
        LogUtil.LogError(string.Format("{0} content error: {1}",xmlPath,xmlString));
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            LogUtil.LogInfo(string.Format("Start serialize model {0} to xml file:{1}", typeof(T), xmlPath));
            File.WriteAllText(xmlPath, xmlString);
            LogUtil.LogInfo(string.Format("End serialize model {0} to xml file:{1}", typeof(T), xmlPath));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogUtil.LogError("an error occur when model to xml, exception:{0}",ex.ToString());
        }           
    }                    
}
```

Comment: Please see the value.CopyTo method [link]http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,715bd5de78456219,references

Comment: Finally, I find out the root cause of this issue. Because of Windows cache mechanism, the content didn't write to disk directly. In order to write content to disk directly, I use the construct of FileStream: FileStream (String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare, Int32, FileOptions)　and set FileOptions as "WriteThrough"